# Node / Angular Authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate a user using node.js and angular.js. I have a node server which has a route pointing to api/login. Users can register and log in everything works. But when I get to the client side, I have no idea where to go. I have set up a http interceptor which send the user back to the login page if a session doesn't exist. I am currently using session express. Below are snippets of my code:

Login Route:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

User.findOne({username: username, password: password}, function(err, user) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
  if(!user) {
    res.status(404).send();
  } else {
    console.log('Set' + user);
    req.session.user = user;
    res.status(200).send();
  }
});
```

Protecting this endpoint:

```
app.get('/api/endpoint', function(req, res) {
if(!req.session.user) {
  console.log('Unauthorized');
  res.status(401).send();
} else {
  console.log('Logged in');
  res.status(200).send();
}
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/login'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/register'));

app.listen(port);
```

I'm not sure if this is detailed enough but I know there's something really simple going wrong here I just cannot see it haha! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is ur router file where u defined the template and controller for login or register ?

Comment: The routing on the client side? If so it is handled via angular ui router. Do you need to see that code?

Comment: Yeah show it maybe i can help u.

Comment: @Wcan - https://jsfiddle.net/geu5qnqh/